# Timestamp Script, monitor changes in column C, set timestamp on column E [how-to]

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

As the title suggests I'm trying to make a script to do exactly that. I've been searching a while but got not good results to base the script on.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please read the [FAQ here](http://stackoverflow.com/help) before posting... your question is not a programing question but a direct code request .*Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions*

Comment: You should fully describe your question in the body. The title is just an attention grabber, it should not be treated as the question.

Comment: This was answered in the Google Apps Script forum that preceded stackoverflow but unfortunately thousands of hours of accumulated knowledge has been deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Using the onEdit event, every time a cell or range is edited, the trigger is fired.  You just need to verify what column was edited.  The event parameter contains a function .getCoumn() which returns an integer of the first column in the edited range.

In the [Apps Script API documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/understanding_events) on events, there is a simplified example of what you are requesting.

```
function onEdit(e) {
      // Check to make sure the edit was on column C
      if(e.range.getColumn() == 3){ 
         // Update column E (two columns over i.e. offset(0[rows],2[columns])
         e.range.offset(0,2).setValue(new Date().toTimeString());
      }
    }
```